# why text wraps floated image?

Tags: html, css

As you know when we float an HTML element, we remove it from normal flow and other elements act as if there was no element at all, they just don't see it. But why text starts to wrap around floated image, isn't it suppose to go underneath the image?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse *absolute positioning* with a *flow layout*. Floated elements are moved to the left/right, and text *does* respect them by wrapping around.